# Android Studio Can't resolve Gradle project

Tags: android, configuration, ide, gradle, android-studio

When moving to a new computer I have lost a drive and now am using a different file path for my programming assets.

When I start up one of my previous working projects in Android Studio I run into an issue with Gradle.

It reads as follows.
Gradle 'Timer' project refresh failed:
            Can't resolve Gradle project. Reason: given path (E:\Media\Documents\Dropbox\Programming\Android\AndroidStudioProjects\Timer\build.gradle) doesn't point to a file

My new gradle path is 'C:\Programs\gradle\gradle-1.6' and when I go to Gradle settings in my project it says that it detects this, however after hitting 'ok' and saving/reloading the project the same error persists.

I have GRADLE_HOME set in the environmental variables.
Other projects that are built on this system work however do give this following error "Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'."

Am I missing a configuration step somewhere?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion oceansize42, but actually that didn't help me fix my problem as it reoccurred after I restarted Android Studio.

After some more searching,I found two files with references back to my old drive.

.idea\workspace.xml
and
.idea\gradle.xml

workspace.xml contained an option "KEY_STORE_PATH" that had an old path.
gradle.xml contained my issue "externalProjectPath" that was giving me the error.

Changing both of these and then restarting fixed my issue completely.

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this problem when moving to a new computer.

What I did was choose to import a project (using build.gradle as import file) rather than open a project.  When prompted about gradle information I didn't supply a gradle home but selected to use the gradle wrapper.