# Gradle home can not be found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

My Android Studio project cannot be built because I get the error:

```
Error running build: Gradle home can not be found
```

Gradle home cannot be found now but it worked before in this project, so I assume it is not about the `GRADLE_USER_HOME` variable. I can build any other project, old and newly created.

It stoped working after I created new activity and deleted it manually. What can be reason for this

EDIT:
I tried to build app today and everything worked, so there is no problem anymore. But still I have no idea what that was.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102038/android-studio-cant-resolve-gradle-project

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing the Gradle `refresh Button` (next to the other Android specific buttons in the toolbar)? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080380/what-gradle-tasks-does-idea-android-studio-run-when-i-press-sync-now-and-the) for more info on this.

If you want to check that your `GRADLE_USER_HOME` is correct then add this task to your build.gradle and run it.

```
 task getHomeDir << {
    println gradle.gradleHomeDir
}
```